# Express.js cant apply stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

When running my HTML+ExpressJS code i have ran into an issue to do with CSS. When i go to dev tools in the browser i see `Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:5000/public/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Code:

ExpressJS

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile('/home/pi/website/index.html');
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('http://localhost:5000'));
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class=title>Hello!</h1>
    <h1 class=title>This page is running NodeJS on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to use `public` in your path for the stylesheet link.

Comment: the stylesheet is located within ```public```

Comment: `public` is considered to be the root of the application therefore, anything living in public is automatically available for reference and does not need the `public` prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link:

```
href="public/style.css"
```

will not work with

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

because that will be looking inside the `public` directory for `public/style.css` in your server file system which means it's actually looking for `public/public/style.css` and I assume you don't have the file system set up that way.  You don't show exactly  where `style.css` is in your server file system, but if it's directly in the `public` directory you are pointing `express.static()` at, then you should be using:

```
href="/style.css"
```